# Rails 4.1.1 with console in production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I keep getting this error since updating to rails 4.1.1 and starting my console in production as: `RAILS_ENV=production rails c`

```
load error: /home/tristan/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/.irbrc
NoMethodError: undefined method `split' for nil:NilClass
    /home/tristan/.rvm/scripts/irbrc.rb:41:in `<top (required)>'
    /home/tristan/joggle/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in `require'
    /home/tristan/joggle/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in `block in require'
    /home/tristan/joggle/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:232:in `load_dependency'
    /home/tristan/joggle/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in `require'
    /home/tristan/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/.irbrc:11:in `<top (required)>'
    /home/tristan/joggle/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:241:in `load'
    /home/tristan/joggle/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:241:in `block in load'
    /home/tristan/joggle/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:232:in `load_dependency'
    /home/tristan/joggle/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:241:in `load'
    /home/tristan/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/lib/ruby/2.1.0/irb/init.rb:236:in `run_config'
    /home/tristan/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/lib/ruby/2.1.0/irb/init.rb:19:in `setup'
    /home/tristan/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/lib/ruby/2.1.0/irb.rb:380:in `start'
    /home/tristan/joggle/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.1.1/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:90:in `start'
    /home/tristan/joggle/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.1.1/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:9:in `start'
    /home/tristan/joggle/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.1.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:69:in `console'
    /home/tristan/joggle/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.1.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:40:in `run_command!'
    /home/tristan/joggle/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.1.1/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
```

Comment: What is on line 41 of:  /home/tristan/.rvm/scripts/irbrc.rb?

Comment: No idea... never touched it before but I can look

Comment: Given that's where the error is, I'd suggest looking there. Possibly a missing ENV variable

Comment: I have the same error :(

Answer (score 0):

I just had this same issue.  I ran 'spring stop' then 'rails c' and it corrected the error.  Something got mucked up with the environment because line 41 of that irbrc.rb file refers to the ENV variable GEM_HOME, which I confirmed was actually set.

Does that fix your issue?